# c function error in R

Tags: r, factorial

I am trying to conduct factorial ANOVA test on R for 2*2 factors ('Sex', 'Avatar', both between-subject factors) and it keeps showing error

> formal argument "between" matched by multiple actual arguments

```
library(ez)
m = ezANOVA(dv=Positives, between=Sex, between=Avatar, wid=Subject, data=avt)
```

Assignment tip was:

> Pass both Sex and Avatar as the between parameter using a vector created with the "c" function.

I tried to use `c(between = Sex, between = Avatar)`, it doesn't work either.

Please, may I ask for help on this code? Many thanks!

Comment: Do you know that anova can give you relationship importance but for factors over a numeric variable. It means that for an ANOVA, you need to have a numerical variable and factors. The purpose is to know how much important are factors over the numerical variable. Moreover, if you want us to help you, you need to give us a reproducible example so we can make tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases it is always worth trying to RTM.

It says

> If a single value, may be specified by name alone; if
> multiple values, must be specified as a .() list.

see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ez/ez.pdf

The manual also has an example, which goes like this:

```
#Run an ANOVA on the mean correct RT data.
rt_anova = ezANOVA(
    data = ANT[ANT$error==0,]
    , dv = rt
    , wid = subnum
    , within = .(cue,flank)
    , between = group
)
```

So you should probably try

```
m = ezANOVA(dv=Positives, between=.(Sex, Avatar), wid=Subject, data=avt)
```